# React test on component's fetchdata returns "cannot read property 'catch' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs, redux, promise, mocha.js, sinon

I have a component `fetchData` using Promise.all with a catch on the `fetchBloomreachData` so the other promise can continue even if `fetchBloomreachData` fails.

If fetchBloomreachData rejects it should still wait for newSearch to resolve. But basically if newSearch fails fetchBloomreachData is irrelevant. So newSearch should still continue even if fetchBloomreachData fails. If newSearch fails then it shouldn't.

Did I overlook something? First time I've seen this error happening for me.

```
ProductListing.fetchData = ({ dispatch }, rawParams, location, clubId) => {
  const nextQuery = getListingParams(rawParams, location.query);
  return Promise.all([
    dispatch(newSearch(nextQuery, clubId, location)),
    dispatch(fetchBloomreachData(nextQuery, location.pathname)).catch(() => {})
  ]);
};
```

After adding the catch this test is failing and the test is saying `cannot read property 'catch' of undefined`

```
it("should fetchBloomreachData", () => {
  const ProductListing = require("src/components/product-listing").ProductListing;
  const bloomreachStub = sinon.stub(listingActions, "fetchBloomreachData").resolves();
  const dispatchStub = sinon.stub();
  ProductListing.fetchData(
    { dispatch: dispatchStub },
    { searchTerm: "" },
    { pathname: "/b/1234" },
    {}
  );
  expect(bloomreachStub).to.have.been.calledWith({ searchTerm: "" }, "/b/1234");
});
```

Comment: Is the redux store setup for your tests different than for your app? The error is telling you that the `dispatch` doesn't return anything.  You are expecting it to return a `Promise`.  That behavior is only supported if you are using redux-thunk middleware.  https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#composition "Any return value from the inner function will be available as the return value of dispatch itself."

Answer (score 0):

Your catch should be appended to the Promise, right now its inside of it.

Correction:

```
ProductListing.fetchData = ({ dispatch }, rawParams, location, clubId) => {
  const nextQuery = getListingParams(rawParams, location.query);
  return Promise.all([
    dispatch(newSearch(nextQuery, clubId, location)),
    dispatch(fetchBloomreachData(nextQuery, location.pathname)),
  ]).catch(() => {});
};
```

Comment: The reason for that is even if `fetchBloomreachData` rejects it should still wait for `newSearch` to resolve. But basically if `newSearch` fails `fetchBloomreachData` is irrelevant. So newSearch should still continue even if fetchBloomreachData fails. If newSearch fails then it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get it working by updating the `dispatchStub` to `const dispatchStub = () => Promise.resolve();`

```
it("should fetchBloomreachData", () => {
  const ProductListing = require("src/components/product-listing").ProductListing;
  const bloomreachStub = sinon.stub(listingActions, "fetchBloomreachData").resolves();
  const dispatchStub = () => Promise.resolve();
  ProductListing.fetchData(
    { dispatch: dispatchStub },
    { searchTerm: "" },
    { pathname: "/b/1234" },
    {}
  );
  expect(bloomreachStub).to.have.been.calledWith({ searchTerm: "" }, "/b/1234");
});
```